# PHP How to insert into a table using a function correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning from a tutorial online, but I can't seem to get my SQL statements to insert into the database. This is my first try at functions. I'm thinking it's the "back-tick" in my SQL statement here:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES (".$values.")";`
```

Anyway here's my code db.php:

```
class DB
{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private 
            $_pdo, 
            $_query, 
            $_error = false, 
            $_results, 
            $_count = 0;
    private function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
            echo 'Connected<br>';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());

        }
    }
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public function query($sql, $params = array())
    {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql))
        {
            $r = 1;
            if (count($params))
            {
                foreach($params as $param)
                {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($r, $param);
                    $r++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute())
            {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();

                echo 'success<br>';             
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function action($action, $table, $where = array())
    {
        if(count($where) === 3)
        {
            $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '<=', '>=');
            $field = $where[0];
            $operator = $where[1];
            $value = $where[2];
            if(in_array($operator, $operators))
            {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
                if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error())
                {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function get($table, $where)
    {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }
    public function delete($table, $where)
    {
        return $this->action('DELETE *', $table, $where);
    }
    public function insert($table, $fields = array())
    {
        if(count($fields))
        {
            $keys = array_keys($fields);
            $values = '';
            $r = 1;
            foreach($fields as $field)
            {
                $values .= '?';
                if($r < count($fields))
                {
                    $values .= ', ';
                }
                $r++;
            }
            //die($values);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES (".$values.")";
            echo $sql;
            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function error()
    {
        return $this->_error;
    }
    public function count()
    {
        return $this->_count;
    }
    public function results()
    {
        return $this->_results;
    }
    public function first()
    {
        return $this->results()[0];
    }
}
```

and here's my index.php:

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->insert('users', array(
'username' => 'Dale',
'password' => 'password',
'salt' => 'salt'
));
if($user){ echo 'true';}
```

I've tried removing the "back-ticks" (that's what the guy in the tutorial called them, (`), but that didn't work. I'm trying to get the index.php to insert the data into my database. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How exactly does this fail?  Is there an error?  What is that error?  If your SQL statement isn't doing what you expect, what is that SQL statement?  You're looking at the code that generates it, but what does it generate and does that output match what you expect?

Comment: Add `$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after `new PDO` line. This way any error in PDO would result in Exception you can display or log.

Comment: The error is that it does not insert the data into the mysql database. It does nothing, the code does nothing.

Comment: I just added that line and this is the error that PDO displays: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value' in C:\wamp642\www\tests\login_system_2\classes\db.php on line 48` and `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value in C:\wamp642\www\tests\login_system_2\classes\db.php on line 48`

Comment: So, you must provide `'name' => 'Some name'` in your array, alongside username, password and salt, or set your database to use some default value for it (ex. null).

Comment: Thanks. That worked a bit, but then I received the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in C:\wamp642\www\tests\login_system_2\classes\db.php on line 50` which is this line: `$this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` I have just received this same error whilst trying to update as well.

Comment: Do I just delete this if it's not relevant anymore? Or is it better to answer my question?